# How do you use MySQL InnoDB tables on OS X?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, innodb

I had trouble using InnoDB MySQL 5.0 on OS X because of a my.cnf settings issue. Listing the gotchas in case it helps anyone:

If InnoDB is disabled, check the error log (hostname.err, in the data directory). I had an empty setting which I changed:

```
 innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
```

Hope this helps someone. I was running a rails app and getting errors with my sessions table.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, please still phrase it as a question.  As the FAQ puts it (http://stackoverflow.com/faq), Jeopardy-style.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- just reworded.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer (and accept it)!

Answer (score 0):

It actually shouldn't be required.  InnoDB will automatically create two transaction log files and ibdata1 in /usr/local/mysql/data on Mac OS X.